# Send value to function in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to send value of TextInput to another Class Function in console.log. My approach is when the button is pressed the value `FromStr` in TextInput will got passed into another class function. Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import receiveMessage from "./receiveMessage"

export default class WeatherProject extends Component{

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
        From:'',
        FromStr:'',
    }
  }

 changeText=(From)=>{
  this.setState({From})
 }
 changeText1=(To)=>{
  this.setState({To})
 }
 onPress = ()=>{
  this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
  receiveMessage.receiveMessage();
 }

render(){
return (
<View>
    <View style={styles.inputFields}>
    <TextInput placeholder="From" id="from" style={styles.fromField} onChangeText={this.changeText} />
  <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
  <Button
      title={"Go Back"}
      color="#f194ff"
      onPress={this.onPress}
  ></Button>
 </View>
    </View>
      </View>

);
}
}

receiveMessage.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class receiveMessage extends Component {

        static receiveMessage=()=>{
        console.log(this.state.FromStr)
      }
  }
```

Comment: `receiveMessage` isn't a valid react component name, it should be PascalCased. What is the relationship between `WeatherProject` and `ReceiveMessage`? Parent-child? Siblings? In react data typically flows in one direction, down the tree from parent to children. Callbacks allow data to passed back up the tree though.

Comment: If you are working in React Native try passing the data to another component by using `props`. check out great tutorial here : https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @RaviSingh  i cant compare it with my code. Can you help me in this solution

Answer (score 1):

React does not allow to pass the data between react components in this way.

Following is way to pass the data between components in React. To get more insights please [follow](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class WeatherProject extends Component {
   render() {
    const messageToPassed = 'Hello';
    return (
      <div>
        <ReceiveMessage message={messageToPassed} />
     </div>
    );
   }
}

const ReceiveMessage = props => <h1>{props.message}</h1>;
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

here we pass the value from sidemenu component by raising an event

App.js

```js
class App extends React.Component {
handleSubmit = (e, data) => console.log(`my data from props`, data);
render() {
    return (
            <Sidemenu 
              onSubmit={(e, data)=>this.handleSubmit(e, data)} />
      );
  }
}
```

SideMenu.js

```
const Sidemenu = props => {
const { onSubmit} = props;
    return (
            <button onClick={(e, type)=>this.onSubmit(e, 'mydata')} />
      );
}
```